# calculating first kind surface integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I would like help calculating the next integral:

$\iint_Szds$ when $S=${$x=u\cos t$ , $y=u\sin t$ , $z=t$ , $0\le u\le1$ , $0\le t\le2\pi$}

Here is what I  did:

$|r'_u\times r'_t|=\sqrt{1+u^2}$

so the integral is:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1t\sqrt{1+u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t$

But that does not seems right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why it does not seem right?

Comment: @serg_1 i tried solving it but got to the wrong answer.

Comment: what is the necessary answer?

Comment: @serg_1 $\pi[\sqrt{2}+ln(1+\sqrt{2})]$

Comment: i've got almost the same answer except $\pi^2[\sqrt2+ln(1+\sqrt(2)]$

Comment: @serg_1 so maybe the book is wrong :S the $\pi^2$ is what made me doubt myself